# Jquery .animate()... returns wrong offsets;

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following code, if one of the conditions is true and run the animate code, why both console.log return the same values (offsets)?

```
$(document).on("click",".box",function(){
            var transparent = $("#transparent");
            var transparent_left = transparent.offset().left;
            var transparent_top = transparent.offset().top;
            var box = $(this);
            var this_top = box.offset().top;
            var this_left = box.offset().left;
            console.log(this_top +" "+this_left);

            if(transparent_top === (this_top + 100)
            && transparent_left === this_left){ 
                box.finish().animate({top: "+=100"});
                transparent.finish().animate({top: "-=100"});
            }else if(transparent_top === this_top
            && transparent_left === (this_left + 100)){ 
                box.finish().animate({left: "+=100"});
                transparent.finish().animate({left: "-=100"});
            }else if(transparent_top === this_top 
            && (transparent_left + 100) === this_left){ 
                box.finish().animate({left: "-=100"});
                transparent.finish().animate({left: "+=100"});
            }else if((transparent_top + 100) === this_top
            && transparent_left === this_left){ 
                box.finish().animate({top: "-=100"});
                transparent.finish().animate({top: "+=100"});
            }

            this_top = box.offset().top;
            this_left = box.offset().left;
            console.log(this_top +" "+this_left);

        });
```

Comment: Animations are asynchrone. When you call `.animate` you queues the animation in an "animation manager"  and the code continue. When you call your second `console.log`, animation did not yet started and the box did not already move.

Comment: You can pass a callback function to the `.animate()` method which is executed after the animation has finished. Check the jQuery docs for details: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: Ok, thank you!
I'll return here if I can't find something. :)

Comment: Thanks you so much! It works perfectly! :)